# Accentuation not working after saving document by mistake with UTF-8 (from 8859-1)

Tags: html, text, format, atom-editor

I re-opened the file (mistake, I didn't make a backup) and atom detected and set the character encoding to utf-8, son when I saved the file, every accent is broken like this:

```
ï¿½ 
<strong><u>GESTIï¿½N</u></strong>
```

Is there any possible solution or should I start formatting the whole text again? (It's pretty long)
It's just a simple html5, no server configurations etc. I've tried undo on my text editor, desktop and similar stuff but it was late when I realized.

Comment: Using any decent text editor, read the text file with the proper encoding and the save it with the original encoding. Not familiar with Atom, but there are plenty of text editors around that allow you to specify a character set when loading and saving.

Comment: I've tried with sublime text and issue persists. I guess the test is just corrupted, nothing to do with save-encodings at this point.

Comment: Is this example actually what the file looks like now? The bytes shown are not 8859-1 representations of a valid UTF-8 sequence. So corruption is not out of the question; it's strange though that it would be corrupted in such a way that only the accented characters would be affected! Are you sure this is not some other encoding it was accidentally saved as?

Comment: I'm sure, that happened me a couple of times with atom. The editor detects utf-8 and when you save it just breaks the accents. Maybe thats why those characters shown are not representation of 8859-1, because they are corrupted character not accents. Anyways, I've done the same proccess in a new file with sublime text and zero problems.